# Moving pushed git commits to a different branch after other people pushed their changes

Tags: git

I have committed some code to the master when actually I gotta be doing it in a separate branch. What's worse, I pushed the changes (more precisely, did a `svn dcommit`, but that shouldn't make any difference) and there are several people who pushed their changes to the master after me. This is what the master looks like now:

```
A (theirs) - B (mine) - C (mine) - D (mine) - E (theirs)
                                              ↑
                                              master
```

I want to move my commits to a separate branch to make it look like this:

```
A (theirs) - E (theirs)
|            ↑
|            master
|
+ - B (mine) - C (mine) - D (mine)
                          ↑
                          newbranch
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVN never forgets. You may only replace existing 'trunk' in with new history. I can tell how to do that using SmartGit

I would recommend you to use cherry-picks: in this case svn:mergeinfo will be translated correctly.

1. I suppose you're on master and have no local changes. Reset master to A (Local->Reset, find A).
2. Now you need to re-apply E. Open Log, find E -> right click -> cherry-pick (in the dialog Cherry-pick & commit).
3. You may now push master to replace your trunk: Remote->"Push advanced", check "Force" checkbox.
4. Now trunk is correct. Create a branch "newbranch" and switch to it.
5. Open Log again, find and select commits B, C, D -> right click -> cherry pick (Cherry-pick & commit again).
6. Press Push. In the dialog that may appear select "Push as new".